# Inserting a row in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, insert, sqlalchemy

Been round the houses on this one, cant seem to get the right syntax.

All I want to do is insert a row into a table in SQLAlchemy. The documentation doesnt make sense to me thought:

```
class sqlalchemy.sql.expression.Insert(table, values=None, inline=False, bind=None, prefixes=None, returning=None, **kwargs)
```

The closest I have come is

```
userChoices = meta.Session.query(model.CompUserChoices).filter(model.CompUserChoices.inmptl_user_name == postdict['userid']).filter(model.CompUserChoices.inmptl_option_id == postdict['leg']).all()

userChoices.insert({model.CompUserChoices.inmptl_user_name:postdict['userid']},\
                                        {model.CompUserChoices.inmptl_option_id:postdict['leg']},\
                                        {model.CompUserChoices.inmptl_comp_choice_id:newChoices[i]})
```

Could someone please tell me the correct syntax!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand what exactly you are trying to do, but adding a row is usually no harder than creating a model object and adding it to the session.

```
userChoices = model.CompUserChoices()
# Do stuff on userChoices
meta.Session.add(userChoices)
meta.Session.commit()  # if you have to commit manually
```

Comment: It is a MetaData object, but you often don't have to deal with it directly. More likely, you deal directly with a Session object.

Comment: Ok, thanks - I just got SQLAlchemy talking to a DB for the first time, with a Session object, so good to know I am on the right track. :-) *happy*